# ModelBinding Issue with a Struct

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, modelbinders

I have a ViewModel which contains the following struct:

```
public struct PricesAndDiscounts
{
    public decimal FlatOff;
    public decimal UnitPrice;
    public decimal TotalDiscount;
    public decimal TotalOptions;
    public decimal TotalOrderPrice;
}
```

The ViewModel is in a heirarchy such that there is a property of type PricesAndDiscounts which is a member of the DisplayRowPriceViewModel which is a member of the ManageOrderEditModel:
-ManageOrderEditModel
--DisplayRowPriceViewModel.

The "shape" of the request is exactly as I would want and expect (see Fiddler screenshot of form items):

[image]

However, at the server, the default modelbinder instantiates the struct as zeros for each of its members. Everything else in the ViewModels were created by the ModelBinder without a problem.

Do I need to create a custom ModelBinder for my custom struct?

**Edit - adding more details**
The signature is:

```
public ActionResult ManageOrder([FromBody]ManageOrderEditModel model)
```

I've tried it without the FromBody attribute. Also, the fact that PricesAndDiscounts is a struct is njot the issue. I changed it to a class and all members come in as zeros, instead of the values you can see in Fiddler from the form.

**ManageOrderEditModel**

```
public class ManageOrderEditModel
{
    public DisplayOptionsInDropDownViewModel DisplayOptionsInDropDownViewModel { get; set; }
    public DisplayRowPriceViewModel DisplayRowPriceViewModel { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RegType { get; set; }
}
```

**DisplayRowPriceViewModel**

```
public class DisplayRowPriceViewModel
{
    public Discount Discount { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfAdditionalLocations { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public PricesAndDiscounts PricesAndDiscounts { get; set; }
    public RegType  RegistrationType { get; set; }
    public decimal RowPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your action method signature? I assume you are POSTing to it.

Comment: @Imran I've edited the post with some more info. Cheers.

Comment: Is it an API controller?

Comment: @haim770 No. I tried the FromBody attribute as a hail mary.

Comment: Can you also share your view model code as the names of the properties are very important in model binding?

Comment: @ImranRashid I've added the relevant ViewModels. It's only that 1 property PricesAndDiscounts which gets initialized to 0s

Comment: Instead of decimal , can you please try with double ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create properties instead of fields like so:

```
public struct PricesAndDiscounts
{
    public decimal FlatOff { get; set; }
    public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDiscount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalOptions { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalOrderPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And hopefully it will work.

Comment: That absolutely worked. Thanks. I never thought of adding properties to a struct.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure How you did it but it seems that there is problem with the way you pass data.

I just created same model as yours and it successfully create structure and assign value to it.

Then I call is using PostMan.

Here is the way I call. ( I passed data as Json)

[image]

Here Is result.

[image]

Another solution to this is make property instead of field in structure. This is suggested by @Imaran Rashid.